# Optional field with strict format

Tags: rust, nom

I am trying to build *nom* parser to examine URLs with ID as UUID

```
rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912
```

I created the following:

```
extern crate uuid;
use uuid::Uuid;

named!(room_uuid<&str, Option<Uuid>>,
    do_parse!(
        tag_s!("rooms") >>
        id: opt!(complete!(preceded!(
            tag_s!("/"),
            map_res!(take_s!(36), FromStr::from_str)
        ))) >>

        (id)
    )
);
```

It handles almost all cases well:

```
assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms"), Done("", None));
assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/"), Done("/", None));
assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912"), Done("", Some(Uuid::parse_str("e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912").unwrap())));
```

Except cases where ID is not a valid UUID:

```
assert!(room_uuid("rooms/123").is_err()); # it fails
# room_uuid("rooms/123").to_result() => Ok(None)
```

As far as I understand it happens because `opt!` converts inner `Err` into `None`.

I would like to have ID as optional section but if it is present it should be a valid UUID.
Unfortunately, I don't understand how to combine both those things: optionality and strict format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only started working with nom myself in the last couple of weeks but I found one way of solving this. It doesn't fit exclusively within a macro but it does give the correct behavior with one modification. I swallow the `/` rather than leave it dangling after when a UUID is not given.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;
extern crate uuid;

use std::str::FromStr;
use nom::IResult;
use uuid::Uuid;

fn room_uuid(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Option<Uuid>> {
    // Check that it starts with "rooms"
    let res = tag_s!(input, "rooms");
    let remaining = match res {
        IResult::Incomplete(i) => return IResult::Incomplete(i),
        IResult::Error(e) => return IResult::Error(e),
        IResult::Done(i, _) => i
    };

    // If a slash is not present, return early
    let optional_slash = opt!(remaining, tag_s!("/"));
    let remaining = match optional_slash {
        IResult::Error(_) |
        IResult::Incomplete(_) => return IResult::Done(remaining, None),
        IResult::Done(i, _) => i
    };

    // If something follows a slash, make sure
    // it's a valid UUID
    if remaining.len() > 0 {
        let res = complete!(remaining, map_res!(take_s!(36), FromStr::from_str));
        match res {
            IResult::Done(i, o) => IResult::Done(i, Some(o)),
            IResult::Error(e) => IResult::Error(e),
            IResult::Incomplete(n) => IResult::Incomplete(n)
        }
    } else {
        // This branch allows for "rooms/"
        IResult::Done(remaining, None)
    }
}

#[test]
fn match_room_plus_uuid() {
    use nom::IResult::*;

    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms"), Done("", None));
    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/"), Done("", None));
    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912"), Done("", Some(Uuid::parse_str("e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912").unwrap())));
    assert!(room_uuid("rooms/123").is_err());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Mike! I also thought about using functions and not only macros but I didn't have an idea how to do it. `/` as remaining part is totally not required thing to have (I just managed to parse it only this way and that is it) so no problem here. However, with `rooms/123` it fails not because of wrong format but because of `Incomplete` (less than 36). Also with `rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912-12312` (valid UUID and some more symbols) it succeeds with just taking 36 out of remaining.
But I get the idea, I will try to improve the solution, thanks once again!

Comment: @Aleksey Very true. I should have made this more robust lol But I'm glad I could help! Good luck!

Comment: Looks like one can use `take_while_s!(|chr| nom::is_hex_digit(chr as u8) || chr == '-')` instead of `take_s!(36)`. This way it fails with `Err(MapRes)`.
Actually my use case suppose that `room` can have nested resources, e.g. `rooms/UUID/tracks/UUID`. That is why I can't just read to the end of line.

Answer (score 2):

Given parsing URLs doesn't need a streaming interface you could use [`synom`](https://docs.rs/synom/0.11.3/synom/) instead.  It was maintained as part of the [`syn`](https://docs.rs/syn/0.12.12/syn/) crate, but is sadly not maintained anymore (it was [merged into `syn`](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn/issues/208) and changed to only process rust tokens).

Sadly `synom` doesn't provide `take_s!` and `eof!` (the latter one is going to forbid the trailing "unparsed" `123`), but it's easy enough to implement those.

Using `eof!` also means you can't return an unparsed `"/"` (although I consider that a good thing); and the nested `option!` needs some unwrapping at the end (you could return `Option<Option<Uuid>>` instead to detect the trailing `"/"`).

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7634c0c2f8a5257baeb6c62eca5205cf&version=stable)

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate synom;

extern crate uuid;
use uuid::Uuid;

macro_rules! take_s {
    ($i:expr, $length:expr) => {{
        let length: usize = $length;
        if 0 == length {
            synom::IResult::Done($i, "")
        } else {
            let mut ci = $i.char_indices().skip(length - 1);
            match ci.next() {
                None => synom::IResult::Error,
                Some(_) => {
                    match ci.next() {
                        None => synom::IResult::Done("", $i),
                        Some((pos, _)) => {
                            let (value, rem) = $i.split_at(pos);
                            synom::IResult::Done(rem, value)
                        },
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }};
}

macro_rules! eof {
    ($i:expr,) => {{
        if $i.is_empty() {
            synom::IResult::Done($i, ())
        } else {
            synom::IResult::Error
        }
    }};
}

named!(room_uuid -> Option<Uuid>,
    do_parse!(
        tag!("rooms") >>
        id: option!(preceded!(
            tag!("/"),
            option!(
                switch!(map!(take_s!(36), str::parse),
                    Ok(v) => value!(v)
                )
            )
        )) >>
        eof!() >>

        (id.unwrap_or(None))
    )
);

fn main() {
    use synom::IResult::*;

    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms"), Done("", None));
    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/"), Done("", None));
    assert_eq!(
        room_uuid("rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912"),
        Done(
            "",
            Some(Uuid::parse_str("e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912").unwrap())
        )
    );
    assert_eq!(room_uuid("rooms/123"), Error);
}
```

Comment: thank you! I wasn't aware of `synom`. I am a little scared to use it because original `nom` has more built-in parsers and documentation and I am newbie enough that I couldn't write something like `take_s` myself (like you did).
As far as I can see `synom::IResult::Error` doesn't contain error itself. Is it okay?

Actually my hole task is to parse URL like: `api/v1/rooms/UUID/tracks/UUID`
Is it possible with `synom`?

Comment: I just realized `synom` isn't maintained anymore.  Maybe [`strom`](https://docs.rs/strom/0.1.1/strom/) is an alternative, but it seems dead too.  Maybe I'll write my own :)  Maybe [`router`](https://docs.rs/router/0.6.0/router/macro.router.html) is a solution in your case?

Comment: Not sure `router` can be used outside of Iron. I build MQTT-based application, so, I need to parse topics and it looks like very custom logic.
I have just add `eof!` to my initial version and it results in `Error`. Bad thing is that it is `Error(Eof)` and I would like in to be `Error(Verify)` or similar.
Still hoping it is possible to implement using `nom`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I got it working with `nom` and the extended URL format `api/v1/rooms/UUID/tracks/UUID`.

The basics are the same as before: you want to check for `eof`, ignore trailing `"/"` and never wait for incomplete results (`alt_complete!` is doing a good job here).

Regarding your `ErrorKind::Verify` wish: I don't think the error kind is actually important, just ignore it, or map it to whatever you want manually.

Be careful with the `alt_complete!` branches: in case of overlaps the preferred option (usually the "longer one") should come first.

I like my `with!` helper, but you could also inline it.

Playground doesn't support `nom`, so no link this time.

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;

extern crate uuid;
use uuid::Uuid;

named!(uuid<&str, Uuid>, preceded!(
    tag_s!("/"),
    map_res!(take_s!(36), str::parse)
));

#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Debug)]
enum ApiRequest {
    Rooms,
    Room { room: Uuid },
    Tracks { room: Uuid },
    Track { room: Uuid, track: Uuid },
}

/// shortcut for: `do_parse!(name: expr >> r: otherexpr >> (r))`
///
/// `otherexpr` should use `name`, otherwise you could just use `preceded!`.
macro_rules! with {
    ($i:expr, $var:ident: $submac:ident!( $($args:tt)* ) >> $($rest:tt)*) => {
        do_parse!($i, $var: $submac!($($args)*) >> r: $($rest)* >> (r));
    };
    ($i:expr, $var:ident: $submac:ident >> $($rest:tt)*) => {
        do_parse!($i, $var: $submac >> r: $($rest)* >> (r));
    };
}

// /api/v1/rooms/UUID/tracks/UUID
named!(apiv1<&str, ApiRequest>, preceded!(tag_s!("/api/v1"),
    alt_complete!(
        preceded!(tag_s!("/rooms"), alt_complete!(
            with!(room: uuid >> alt_complete!(
                preceded!(tag_s!("/tracks"), alt_complete!(
                    with!(track: uuid >> alt_complete!(
                        // ... sub track requests?
                        value!(ApiRequest::Track{room, track})
                    ))
                    |
                    value!(ApiRequest::Tracks{room})
                ))
                // other room requests
                |
                value!(ApiRequest::Room{room})
            ))
            |
            value!(ApiRequest::Rooms)
        ))
        // | ... other requests
    )
));

named!(api<&str, ApiRequest>, terminated!(
    alt_complete!(
        apiv1
        // | ... other versions
        // also could wrap in new enum like:
        //     apiv1 => { ApiRequest::V1 }
        //     |
        //     apiv2 => { ApiRequest::V2 }
    ),
    tuple!(
        alt_complete!(tag_s!("/") | value!("")), // ignore trailing "/"
        eof!() // make sure full URL was parsed
    )
));

fn main() {
    use nom::IResult::*;
    use nom::ErrorKind;

    let room = Uuid::parse_str("e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912").unwrap();
    let track = Uuid::parse_str("83d235e8-03cd-420d-a8c6-6e42440a5573").unwrap();

    assert_eq!(api("/api/v1/rooms"), Done("", ApiRequest::Rooms));
    assert_eq!(api("/api/v1/rooms/"), Done("", ApiRequest::Rooms));
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Room { room })
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Room { room })
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/tracks"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Tracks { room })
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/tracks/"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Tracks { room })
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/tracks/83d235e8-03cd-420d-a8c6-6e42440a5573"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Track{room, track})
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/tracks/83d235e8-03cd-420d-a8c6-6e42440a5573/"),
        Done("", ApiRequest::Track{room, track})
    );
    assert_eq!(api("/api/v1"), Error(ErrorKind::Alt));
    assert_eq!(api("/api/v1/foo"), Error(ErrorKind::Alt));
    assert_eq!(api("/api/v1/rooms/123"), Error(ErrorKind::Eof));
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/bar"),
        Error(ErrorKind::Eof)
    );
    assert_eq!(
        api("/api/v1/rooms/e19c94cf-53eb-4048-9c94-7ae74ff6d912/tracks/83d235e8-03cd-420d-a8c6-6e42440a5573/123"),
        Error(ErrorKind::Eof)
    );
    assert_eq!(api("/api/v2"), Error(ErrorKind::Alt));
}
```

You could also use a more strict `alt_full_opt_slash!` branch method, which would ensure a branch only matches if it fully parsed the input.

You could then use a more "flat" way (although nested branches should still be working) to parse the alternatives (although this means you might end up parsing some UUIDs more than once; also now all errors are of kind `Alt`):

```
/// Similar to alt_complete, but also requires the branch parses until
/// the end of the input (but ignores a trailing "/").
macro_rules! alt_full_opt_slash {
    (__impl_push2 ($i:expr,) ($($new:tt)*), $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl ($i, $($new)*), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl_push2 ($i:expr, $($result:tt)+) ($($new:tt)*), $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl ($i, $($result)+ | $($new)*), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl_push ($($result:tt)*) ($($new:tt)*), $($rest:tt)*) => {
        // modify branch:
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl_push2 ($($result)*) (
            terminated!(
                $($new)*,
                tuple!(
                    alt_complete!(tag_s!("/") | value!("")), // ignore trailing "/"
                    eof!() // make sure full URL was parsed
                )
            )
        ), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl ($($result:tt)*), $e:ident | $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl_push ($($result)*) ( $e ), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl ($($result:tt)*), $subrule:ident!( $($args:tt)*) | $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl_push ($($result)*) ( $subrule!($($args)*) ), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl ($($result:tt)*), $subrule:ident!( $($args:tt)* ) => { $gen:expr } | $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl_push ($($result)*) ( $subrule!($($args)*) => { $gen } ), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl ($($result:tt)*), $e:ident => { $gen:expr } | $($rest:tt)*) => {
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl_push ($($result)*) ( $e => { $gen } ), $($rest)*)
    };
    (__impl ($i:expr, $($result:tt)*), __end) => {
        alt_complete!($i, $($result)*)
    };
    ($i:expr, $($rest:tt)*) => {{
        alt_full_opt_slash!(__impl ($i, ), $($rest)* | __end)
    }};
}

// /api/v1/rooms/UUID/tracks/UUID
named!(apiv1<&str, ApiRequest>, preceded!(tag_s!("/api/v1"),
    alt_full_opt_slash!(
        do_parse!(
            tag_s!("/rooms") >>
            (ApiRequest::Rooms)
        )
        |
        do_parse!(
            tag_s!("/rooms") >>
            room: uuid >>
            (ApiRequest::Room{room})
        )
        |
        do_parse!(
            tag_s!("/rooms") >>
            room: uuid >>
            tag_s!("/tracks") >>
            (ApiRequest::Tracks{room})
        )
        |
        do_parse!(
            tag_s!("/rooms") >>
            room: uuid >>
            tag_s!("/tracks") >>
            track: uuid >>
            (ApiRequest::Track{room, track})
        )
    )
));

named!(api<&str, ApiRequest>, alt_complete!(
    apiv1
    // | ... other versions
    // also could wrap in new enum like:
    //     apiv1 => { ApiRequest::V1 }
    //     |
    //     apiv2 => { ApiRequest::V2 }
));
```